# How to include multiple addresses in filter of ether.js?

Tags: ethers.js, filters

I want to use [provider.on()](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider--event-methods) function of ethers.js to listen to the `Transfer` event of contracts. My [filter](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/concepts/events/#events--filters) looks like this:

```
   let filter = {
        address: tokenAddress,
        topics: [
            utils.id("Transfer(address,address,uint256)")
        ]
    };
```

It works well for one tokenAddress. I want it to listen to more tokenAddress. I try `address:[tokenAddress1,tokenAddress2]` but it doesn't work.how can I achieve it?